# Possible error on Wiki-page for Dual_matroid

Tags: matroids, reference-works

On the Wiki-page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_matroid you find the following part:[image]

It reads "..the graphic matroids of planar graphs are self-dual". This claim cannot be right. Do you agree? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: At least the argumentaiotn on WP only shows that taking the dual (graph or maroid) and taking the matroid of a graph commute - the dual of the matroid is the matroid of the dual. This won't justify the claim. - Also, the reference talks about planar graphs only peripherically. Best guess is "Let us therefore define a _planar_ matroid as one that is both graphic and co-graphic. Such a matroid corresponds to a pair of dual planar graphs." Of course an (unordered) _pair_ of dual planar graphs would remain fixed under taking duals ... But in the end I know too little about matroids

Comment: As I understand "self-dual" it means $M \cong M^*$ where the bases of $M^*$ are formed by complements of the bases of $M$, i.e., $\mathcal B(M^*) = \{E(M)\setminus B: B \in \mathcal B(M)\}$ where $E(M)$ is the ground set of $M$.

Comment: It seems like the commutativity of taking the dual and the matroid is only enough to say that "the graphic matroids of **self-dual** planar graphs are self-dual". Try taking a simple non-self-dual planar graph and see if it becomes a counterexample.

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense. So, it possibly a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence in question is correct, if rather misleading when not taken in context. The key here is the definition of the "self-dual family of matroids" given in the first sentence:

> Self-dual matroid family: a family $\mathscr{F}$ of matroids such that
>   $M \in \mathscr{F}$  $\Longleftrightarrow$ $M^*$ is also in $\mathscr{F}$.

The sentence in question is misleading because it is making a statement about a `family of matroids` without explicitly using the word `family`.
The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_matroid#Matroid_families) has now been edited to read

> Thus, the family of graphic matroids of planar graphs is self-dual.

Now, let's see why that is true. Let $\mathscr{P}$ be the family of all matroids arising from planar graphs and let $M \in \mathscr{P}$. 
Then there is planar graph $G$ such that $M=M(G)$. 
Since $G$ is planar, so is its dual graph $G^*$. 
Now consider the matroid $M(G^*)$. 
From, e.g., the circuit axioms of a matroid one can deduce that $M(G^*)$ is isomorphic to $M^*$, the dual matroid of $M$.